# find matching characters in two strings at different indexes

Tags: java, regex, string

I am a C++ programmer. Out of interest, I am developing a java application.

I have two strings in java:

```
String word1 = "Fold";
String word2 = "Flow";
```

Now I need a function to get the count of matching characters in both strings but those that are at different indexes. The strings could be of any length but always both words will be of the same length.

Added:
We should increment count for a character by that many occurrences in both words. Ex: abcd and xyaa should return 1, but abca and xaay should return 2. Hope it is clear now.

For ex:, the count for the above example should be 2 (Only letters 'o' and 'l' are considered. Though letter 'f' is present in both words, it is not considered since it is present at the same index on both strings.

My method was to create two map variables Map and initialize it with 0 for all characters. Then calculate count of how many times each letter occurs in both strings and finally check how many of these characters have count more than one.

Ex:

```
    Map<Character, Integer> word_count_1 = createMap(); // initialize with a:0, b:0, c:0,...z:0
    Map<Character, Integer> word_count_2 = createMap(); // initialize with a:0, b:0, c:0,...z:0

    int count, value;

    for (int i=0; i<word1.length(); i++)
    {
        if (word1.charAt(i) != word2.charAt(i))
        {
            value = word_count_1.get(word1.charAt(i));
            word_count_1.put(word1.charAt(i), ++value);

            value= word_count_2.get(word2.charAt(i));
            word_count_2.put(word2.charAt(i), ++value);
        }
    }

    Set set = word_count_2.entrySet();
    Iterator i = set.iterator();
    Map.Entry<Character, Integer> iter;

    while(i.hasNext())
    {
        iter = (Map.Entry)i.next();
        if ( (iter.getValue() > 0) && (word_count_1.get(iter.getKey())) > 0 )
        {
            count++; // This line has a bug. We shall ignore it for now
        }
    }
```

Is there any other better method to get the count instead of what I am trying to do? I just dont get a good feeling about what I have done.

Edited:

The line count++ (that I mentioned having a bug) should be changed to following to give correct result:

```
int letterCount1 = word_count_1.get(iter.getKey());
int letterCount2 = iter.getValue();
if ( (letterCount1 > 0) && (letterCount2 > 0 )
{
    int minVal = letterCount1;
    if (minVal > letterCount2)
        minVal = letterCount2;
    count+= minVal;
}
```

Comment: Your example should be 2: 'o' and 'l'.

Comment: There's nicer syntax to iterate but the counting looks fine.

Comment: I don't think your idea is even close to what you aim at. How would you differentiate between F and o?

Comment: What if you have more than one instance of the same letter in a string and one of them is in the same index as in the other string? Should you count it?

Comment: @Bifz Missed it, thanks

Comment: I would adapt my code to use [Levenshtein Distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) and use a [library](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html) for the calculation. Here's an [on-line calculator where you can see value for your example strings](http://planetcalc.com/1721/?source=Flow&target=Fold)

Comment: @MaxZoom Yes, and I got the result I was expecting

Comment: @Gavriel If the letter appears at same index in both strings, it should be ignored only at that instance. For ex: word1="aba", word2="aac", count should be 1

Comment: Why 1? abc vs xab would be 2, wouldn't? So why is aab different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nicer syntax to iterate over the set (see example below) but the actual counting looks fine.

```
Map<Character, Integer> word_count_1 = createMap(); // initialize with a:0, b:0, c:0,...z:0
Map<Character, Integer> word_count_2 = createMap(); // initialize with a:0, b:0, c:0,...z:0<Character, Integer>

int count, value;

for (int i=0; i<word1.length(); i++)
{
    if (word1.charAt(i) != word2.charAt(i))
    {
        value = word_count_1.get(word1.charAt(i));
        word_count_1.put(word1.charAt(i), ++value);

        value= word_count_2.get(word2.charAt(i));
        word_count_2.put(word2.charAt(i), ++value);
    }
}

Set set = word_count_2.entrySet();
for(<Map.Entry<Character, Integer>> iter:set) 
{
    if ( (iter.getValue() > 0) && (word_count_1.get(iter.getKey())) > 0 )
    {
        count++; // This line has a bug. We shall ignore it for now
    }
}
```

Comment: No prob, should be easy enough for you to pick up since your into C++ :)

Answer (score 1):

Java 8 Solution

```
  public int duplicates(String wordOne, String wordTwo ){
    Set<Character> charSet = new HashSet(109);
    wordOne.chars().mapToObj(i -> (char)i).forEach(letter->charSet.add(letter));

    int count = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < wordTwo.length(); i++)
      if( charSet.contains(wordTwo.charAt(i)) && wordTwo.charAt(i) != wordOne.charAt(i) )
        count++;

    return count;
  }

duplicates("Fold", "Flow"); // -> 2
```

Comment: This would yield wrong result for inputs abcd vs xyaa. I would expect output 1, but your solution would give output 2.

Comment: Oh ok, sure. However, this was not clear from the problem description. Thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Create set which contains word1's unique chars
Set<Character> word1Chars = new HashSet<>();

for(int i = 0; i< word1.length(); i++)
{
    char ch = word1.charAt(i);
    word1Chars.add(ch);
}

// Count how many chars in word2 are contained in word1 but in another position
int count = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < word2.length(); i++)
{
    char ch = word2.charAt(i);
    if(ch != word1.charAt(i) && word1Chars.contains(ch))
    {
        count++;
    }
}
```

EDIT: You have to take into consideration that you may get a different counting depending on which word you iterate. E.g: "abc" and "daa"; "abc" has 1 but "daa" has 2.
If you want the total of correspondences in both words you need to modify this code accordingly.

Comment: Same as another solution, this would yield wrong result for inputs abcd vs xyaa. I would expect output 1, but your solution would give output 2.

Comment: No, it will output 1. But if you swap the words, then it will output 2.
What you're asking gives a different result depending on the order of your strings.

Comment: Irrespective of the order, I must get the same output.

Comment: `abcd` has 1 letter from `xyaa` but `xyaa` has 2 letters from `abcd`

Comment: In your example abcd and xyaa, there is only one instance of 'a' that are in both words but different position. I shall edit the question to make it clear.

Comment: How is there only 1??? Looking up in `abcd` and counting letters in `xyaa`, you have: 0 (x) + 0 (y) + 1 (a) + 1 (a).
Both 'a' in `xyaa` exist in `abcd` and both are in a different position. How can this be 1??

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to initialize maps for all the characters.

```
public static int matchCharCountInDifferentIndex(String word1, String word2) {
    Map<Character, Integer> word_count_1 = new HashMap<>();
    Map<Character, Integer> word_count_2 = new HashMap<>();

    for (int i=0; i<word1.length(); i++)
    {
        if (word1.charAt(i) != word2.charAt(i))
        {
            word_count_1.compute(word1.charAt(i), (k, v) -> v == null ? 1 : v + 1);
            word_count_2.compute(word2.charAt(i), (k, v) -> v == null ? 1 : v + 1);
        }
    }

    int count = 0;
    for (Map.Entry<Character, Integer> e : word_count_2.entrySet())
    {
        count += Math.min(e.getValue(), word_count_1.getOrDefault(e.getKey(), 0));
    }

    System.out.printf("word1=%s word2=%s result=%d%n", word_count_1, word_count_2, count);
    return count;
}
```

Tests are

```
matchCharCountInDifferentIndex("Fold", "Flow"); // -> word1={d=1, l=1, o=1} word2={w=1, l=1, o=1} result=2
matchCharCountInDifferentIndex("abca", "xaay"); // -> word1={a=2, b=1, c=1} word2={a=2, x=1, y=1} result=2
```

In this code

```
map.compute(key, (k, v) -> v == null ? 1 : v + 1);
```

is equivalent to

```
map.put(key, map.getOrDefault(key, 0) + 1);
```

And

```
map.getOrDefault(key, 0)
```

is equivalent to

```
map.containsKey(key) ? map.get(key) : 0;
```

Comment: Have no idea what this line does:  word_count_1.compute(word1.charAt(i), (k, v) -> v == null ? 1 : v + 1); Care to explain?

Comment: Solutions using set is going to return wrong result if the same letter appears at 2 unmatched positions in the words. Ex: abca and xaay would give output 1, whereas I expect 2.